# How to do Pagination in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a dynamic array. I want to traverse into that array and add pagination to it. Currently, I am using ng-repeat for traverse but how I can add pagination with ng-repeat. Please help me into this?

Answer (score 1):

It is simple.
First decide how many items need to be displayed on a single page. Let us assume that to be 10;

```
var resultsPerPage = 10;
```

Now based on total results, you can calculate number of pages.

```
var noOfPages = Math.ceil(array.length / resultsPerPage);
```

Now you need to track the current page. Initially it will be 1;

```
var currentPage = 1;
```

Now in view, you can display current page values by multiplying currentPage with resultsPerPage

For example if you are in page 1, you need to display values from 0 to 9. So you need to do some thing like this.

```
var endIndex = (currentPage * resultsPerPage) - 1;
var startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * resultsPerPage;
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you need pagination for ui, I suggest [smart table plugin](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/) 
its easy to integrate and use.

Comment: There is no need any plgin.You can do it with your own custom angular script

Comment: why to rebuild the wheel ? if he want to display something familiar ( table  for example ) with pagination there is already a tone of already maked directives

Answer (score 0):

If you have your current page and number of rows in page in

```
var params = {
    'page' : 1,
    'count' : 10
};
```

then do

```
data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
```

However, if you want to build a table, consider [ngTable](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table).

Answer (score 0):

With the ng-repeat you only display data from a variable in the `$scope`.

You have to add another system to query data and set them in the `$scope` for the ng-repeat. 
there is a lot of pagination system but this is a small example :

CONTROLLER :

```
$scope.displayMe = [ .... ] ;
$scope.previous= function(){
   // do your logic to get the good data
   $scope.displayMe = newData ;
}
$scope.next= function(){
   // do your logic to get the good data
   $scope.displayMe = newData ;
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="data in displayMe"> {{data }} </div>
<button ng-click="previous()"><-- </button>
<button ng-click="next()">--> </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many plug-n-play pagination directives are available.

I am using **dir-pagination**. Because this is easy to add into project. No need to do any set-up or logic in your controller.

Just add an attribute, drop in your navigation wherever you like.

[This is the link for dir-pagination](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination)